# Finding certain item in a tree (C)

Tags: c, tree, segmentation-fault

I have a tree with structures. I need to find the min whose number is max (given).

```
    Item this_word (link h, int max){
        Item word;
        if (h == NULL) 
            return 0;
        if (h->item->acc == max){
            word = h->item; 
            this_word(h->l, max);
        }
        else{ 
            this_word(h->l, max);
            this_word(h->r, max);
        }
        return word;
    }
```

But I get a segmentation fault..

Comment: Is the link variable a pointer? Because you're accessing it like one

Comment: Where exactly is your segfault? Have you run the program in a debugger? Please show the definition of `Item` and `link` types.

Comment: @BackDoorNoBaby typedefs are evil

Comment: I also think your `else` statement should be two `else if` statements

Comment: After `word = h->item;`, why is code calling `this_word(h->l, max);` instead of just returning `word`?  Suggest providing example of values that meet " find the min whose number is max".

Comment: @BackDoorNoBaby yes, link is a pointer

Comment: @chux because I want the minimum and not the first one. That's why if it's in that node I no longer search on the right side of the tree because those are superior.

Comment: @Heather _nothing_ in this post indicates that the tree has any sorted values so is the "I no longer search on the right side of the tree because those are superior" now a new fact that you are imposing on this post?

Comment: `this_word(h->l, max);` and `this_word(h->l, max);` serve no purpose as they do not affect anything in the function aside from using up CPU time..

Answer (score 0):

Your code segfaults when `h!= NULL` and `h->item->acc == max` holds. In this case the else branch is executed and word is returned, which has not been set before. You can solve this by properly assigning a value to word.

```
Item this_word (link h, int max){
        Item word;
        if (h == NULL) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (h->item->acc == max) {
            word = h->item; 
            this_word(h->l, max);
        } else { 
            // assign a certain value to word
            this_word(h->l, max);
            this_word(h->r, max);
        }
        return word;
    }
```

As far as I can see your code is a bit weird, which is the case because one cannot fully understand what you are trying to to based on your question. In order to improve the quality of the anser, provide a better question (add code, explain context, etc.)

Comment: I did that and I still get a segmentation fault. The struct has a string and a number. The tree is organized through the strings and I want to return the struct which has the number given. When there are two like "one" and "computer" with that number I want to return "computer" since it's in alphabetical order

Comment: @Heather so the tree is sorted with respect to the strings. And you want to get the "smallest" string which has a certain number? You should definitly add this to your question! Is the tree proper initialised? Can a segfault be caused if NULL is returned? I guess we need more code ..

Comment: I used `void init() { 
  head = NULL; 
}` to initialize the tree.  When NULL is returned where?

Comment: Please add the points mentioned before to your question by editing it. And also add more code. The context .. what other functions you use .. the main function .. etc.